# JavaFX ScatterChart: data points behind axis?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a scatterchart in JavaFX. However, some of the data points are partially hidden behind the axes:

[image: Here is a screenshot.]

How can I bring the data points in front of the axis? This is the code that I've used after creating the plot, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

```
 for (Series s : plot.getData()) {
        for (Object d : s.getData()) {
            if (d instanceof Data) {
                Data dat = (Data) d;
                dat.getNode().toFront();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could instead decrease the lower bound of your x axis a little, so neither would overlay the other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my x axis is on a scale from 0 to 1 and I want it to remain that way. I want the data points with a x-value of 0 to lay on top of the axis.